# How to create 2 arrays of 2 fields in the same collection MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection named `usersT` with a field named `created_at`. I calculate the sum of the rows that have the same values for the minute and hour by using this query:
[image]

And this is how it looks like:
[image]

Now, I would like to build 2 arrays using both fields: one of them with an hour and minute; and the other with the sum calculated above.

For example, regarding the data shown in the first picture, the array containing hours and minutes would be something like:

> [8:47, 8;51, 7:29, 9:59, 4:18, . . ., 9:53]

The other array containing the sum would be:

> [721, 759, 750, 766, 1495, . . ., 705]

How can I get this? I tried writing this query:

```
[12:39, 25/10/2017] Esther Uni: db.usersT.aggregate([{$group: {_id: {$first: {hora: {$hour: '$created_at'}, minuto: {$minute: '$created_at'}}}, total: {$first: {$sum: 1}}}}])
```

using $first operator but I do not get a solution

Comment: You can try  add `{$group: {_id: null, horaminuto: {$push: {$concat:['$_id.hora', ':', '$_id.minuto']}}, total: {$push: "$total"}}}` to aggregation pipeline after first group stage.

Comment: @Veeram thanks veeram, I already tried that but I get an error that seems to be related with the memory: “BSONObj size: 46314459 (0x2C2B3DB) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: id: 0”

Comment: Np. Do you need to run the query for entire collection ? Is there a match  can use ?